# Bundler crashes when creating new Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundler

Versions:

- Ruby 1.9.3p194
- Rails 3.2.13
- Bundler 1.3.5

When I run `rails new new_app`, I get:

```
         run  bundle install
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/ui.rb:36:in `initialize': undefined method `[]' for #<Thor::Shell::Color:0x00000002b25708> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:12:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'
```

The code in question in `ui.rb` is:

```
  def initialize(options = {}) 
    if options["no-color"] || !STDOUT.tty?
      Thor::Base.shell = Thor::Shell::Basic
    end 
    @shell = Thor::Base.shell.new
    @level = ENV['DEBUG'] ? "debug" : "info"
  end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438118/rails-new-bundle-install might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it on my own. The post MrYoshiji linked above suggested that it was an incompatibility between Ruby and Rails. This was basically the problem - it was a version incompatibility, which is best resolved by using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to install a local (user-specific) copy of Ruby, Rails, etc.

But I had already installed RVM. There was a further issue that had to be resolved - RVM was not running as a function, which you can solve by setting your terminal to load `/etc/profile` on startup. How to do so in gnome-terminal is explained on the RVM site [here](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/).

However, this wasn't a good solution for me because it prevented my local bash files (such as `~/.bash_aliases`) from loading. So instead of changing that terminal setting as shown on the RVM site, I opened `~/.bashrc` and added the line `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`. After restarting the terminal, everything was working fine - the right copies of Ruby and Rails were being used, and I was no longer encountering that error when I tried to create a new Rails app (presumably because I'm now using local copies of the gems as well, rather than a system-wide copy installed via APT).